# Fail to serve static files in deployed Django app (Docker, gunicorn, whitenoise, Heroku)

Tags: django, docker, heroku, gunicorn, whitenoise

I have built a Django REST API which serves JSON responses only. My problem is, in production (deployed on Heroku with debug=False) the app does not seem to serve relevant static files needed for the proper styling of the admin interface (only use case for static files). Note, in development (localhost with debug=True) the admin interface is properly styled.

Going to the admin route at the deployed (Heroku) address, the content is delivered but without any styling. The browser developer tools indicate that style sheets could not be loaded due to a 500 error code. Django logging output reveals the below detail.

```
django.request ERROR    Internal Server Error: /static/admin/css/base.1f418065fc2c.css
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/app/secure_my_spot/custom_middleware/request_logging.py", line 30, in __call__
print(f"Content: {response.content}")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 407, in content
raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: This WhiteNoiseFileResponse instance has no `content` attribute. Use `streaming_content` instead.
```

I have gone into the Heroku dyno and verified that the static files, which cause the 500 error, are in fact in the static_root as per Django's settings.py. I have been spending a significant amount of time scouring the internet for clues as to what might cause the files to not be served in production but whatever I have tried, it did not work.

Below is a curated summary of the relevant files and settings.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update && apk add \
    gcc \
    libc-dev \
    python3-dev \
    musl-dev \
    postgresql-dev \
    vim \
    bash --no-cache --upgrade

RUN pip install \
    pipenv \
    psycopg2

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./

RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --pre

COPY . .

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

CMD gunicorn secure_my_spot.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

**heroku.yml**

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - chmod u+x heroku_entrypoint.sh
run:
  web: ./heroku_entrypoint.sh
```

**heroku_entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py migrate --noinput
gunicorn secure_my_spot.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django_extensions",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "app",
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "secure_my_spot.custom_middleware.request_logging.RequestLogging",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
```

**wsgi.py**

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "secure_my_spot.settings")

if settings.DEBUG:
    application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
else:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this](https://cheat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django/static_files.html#the-whitenoise-app) I moved the Django SecurityMiddleware to the top of the middleware array, immediately followed by the WhiteNoiseMiddleware (see below). This little change did the trick and all static assets are now served as expected.

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "secure_my_spot.custom_middleware.request_logging.RequestLogging",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a good explanation as to why this mere change in the order of the middleware array elements causes this issue. Perhaps moving the WhiteNoiseMiddleware before the CorsMiddleware is important even though the error messages did not indicate any CORS errors.